# Size an array within a class array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, initialization

I got a class which holds an array and another object:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public double[] myArray;
    public int otherObject;
};
```

Now I want to create different array instances of that class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass[] classArray1 = new MyClass[classArraySize1]
    MyClass[] classArray2 = new MyClass[classArraySize2]
};
```

But how do I size `myArray` for every `classArray` individually?

They should be assigned values like this later:

```
classArray1[i].myArray[j] = 1.0;
classArray2[n].myArray[k] = 2.0;
```

Comment: What is the question? Btw you've not even initialized your array with instances of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a constructor to your class that you can use to initialize the array to a given size:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public double[] myArray;
    public int otherObject;

    public MyClass(int size)
    {
        myArray = new double[size];
    }
}
```

You can then set the size of `myArray` for an array of `MyClass` with something like:

```
int numMyClasses = 123;
int sizeMyArray = 456;

// Manually
MyClass[] classArray1 = new MyClass[numMyClasses];
for (int i = 0; i < numMyClasses; i++)
    classArray1[i] = new MyClass(sizeMyArray);

// LINQ
MyClass[] classArray2 = new MyClass[numMyClasses]
    .Select(x => new MyClass(sizeMyArray)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Lol. You arnt reinventing the wheel... you are building a time machine :D.

Answer (score 0):

You can set them on the fly like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass[] classArray1 = new MyClass[classArraySize1]
    MyClass[] classArray2 = new MyClass[classArraySize2]

    classArray1[i].myArray = new double[whatever_size_you_want];
    classArray2[i].myArray = new double[whatever_size_you_want];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
MyClass[] classArray1 =
{
    new MyClass { myArray = new double[classArraySize1] },
    new MyClass { myArray = new double[classArraySize1] }
};

MyClass[] classArray2 =
{
    new MyClass { myArray = new double[classArraySize2] },
    new MyClass { myArray = new double[classArraySize2] }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is (in my opinion) the best way to go.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public double[] myArray;
    public int otherObject;

    public MyClass(int ArraySize)
    {
        myArray = new double[ArraySize];
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass custom1 = new MyClass(10); // <-- new instance of your class
    custom1.myArray // <-- holds your array
    custom1.otherObject // <-- holds your object
}
```